# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFB9423B29 in Opencv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location

Tags: c++, opencv, adaptive-threshold

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



Mat imgOriginal, imgDilate, imgCanny, imgGray, imgBlur, imgWrap, imgCrop,imgScan;
vector<Point> initialPoints, docPoints;

float w = 590, h = 360;

Mat preProcessing(Mat img)
{
    cvtColor(img, imgGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(imgGray, imgBlur, Size(3, 3), 3, 0);
    Canny(imgBlur, imgCanny, 25, 75);
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3));
    dilate(imgCanny, imgDilate, kernel);
    return imgDilate;
}

vector<Point> getContours(Mat image)
{
    vector< vector<Point >> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(image, contours, hierarchy ,RETR_EXTERNAL,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    vector<vector<Point >> conPoly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

    vector<Point> biggest;
    int maxArea = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        int area = contourArea(contours[i]);
        cout << area << endl;

    
        if (area > 1000)
        {
            float peri = arcLength(contours[i], true);
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], conPoly[i], 0.02 * peri, true);

            if (area > maxArea && conPoly[i].size() == 4)
            {
                //drawContours(imgOriginal, conPoly, i, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 5);
                biggest = { conPoly[i][0], conPoly[i][1] , conPoly[i][2] , conPoly[i][3] };
                maxArea = area;
            }   
            
        }
    }
    return biggest;
}
void drawPoints(vector<Point> points, Scalar color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        circle(imgOriginal, points[i], 10, color, FILLED);
        putText(imgOriginal, to_string(i), points[i], FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, color, 2);
    }
}

vector<Point> reorder(vector<Point> points)
{
    vector<Point> newPoints;
    vector<int> sumPoints, subPoints;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sumPoints.push_back(points[i].x + points[i].y);
        subPoints.push_back(points[i].x - points[i].y);
    }
    newPoints.push_back(points[min_element(sumPoints.begin(), sumPoints.end()) - sumPoints.begin()]); // 0
    newPoints.push_back(points[max_element(subPoints.begin(), subPoints.end()) - subPoints.begin()]); // 1
    newPoints.push_back(points[min_element(subPoints.begin(), subPoints.end()) - subPoints.begin()]); // 2
    newPoints.push_back(points[max_element(sumPoints.begin(), sumPoints.end()) - sumPoints.begin()]); // 3

    return newPoints;
    
}

Mat getWarp(Mat img, vector<Point> points, float w, float h)
{
    Point2f src[4] = { points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3] };
    Point2f des[4] = { {0.0f,0.0f },{w,0.0f },{0.0f,h },{w,h} };

    Mat matrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src, des);
    warpPerspective(img, imgWrap, matrix, Point(w, h));

    return imgWrap;

}
```

**At This point error occurs**  *In adaptiveThreshold*
Error :
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFB9423B29 in Opencv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location

```
Mat Scanner(Mat img)
{
    adaptiveThreshold(img, imgScan, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 3, 11); //Error 
    return imgScan;
}
```

**Error in only this ^^^^^ part of code**

rest of the code working only error occurs in  adaptiveThreshold

```
int main()
{
    string path = "resource/document5.jpg";
    imgOriginal = imread(path);
    resize(imgOriginal, imgOriginal,Size(1080,720));

    //image processing 
    imgDilate = preProcessing(imgOriginal);

    //Get contours
    initialPoints = getContours(imgDilate);

    //draw points
    docPoints = reorder(initialPoints);
    //drawPoints(docPoints, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    //drawPoints(initialPoints, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
    imgWrap = getWarp(imgOriginal, docPoints, w, h);
    

    //Crop
    Rect roi(5, 5, w - (2 * 5), h - (2 * 5));
    imgCrop = imgWrap(roi);

    //scan
    Scanner(imgCrop);

    imshow("imgOrignal contours", imgOriginal);
    imshow("imgDilate", imgDilate);
    imshow("imgWrap", imgWrap);
    imshow("imgCrop", imgCrop);
    imshow("imgScan", imgScan);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

In scanner part i use adaptiveThreshold but it shows error
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFB9423B29 in Opencv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. Please make a [mre] if we're going to have a chance of finding the problem.

Comment: Regarding **Error in only this ^^^^^ part of code**, unfortunately one of the things you quickly learn when writing non-trivial programs is very often a bug mortally wounds a program, but the program manages to stagger on for some time afterward before falling down and dying at a different location. Locating and inspecting the crash site is important as it contains clues about the true nature of the bug, but the location of the bug may be far away in terms of both time and code.

Comment: Also never assume you have only one bug. Often0multiple mistakes bugs gang up on you and look like one bug.

Comment: Good that you made it into a reproducible example. It's not minimal, but hey, this is much better that not being able to compile it. I'm getting `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.3.0) /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-4.3.0/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1647: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'adaptiveThreshold'`

Comment: So, wrong source type it seems (I have no clue what that means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert input image to gray to use adaptive threshold
Use cvtcolor to do it